# How to add offset to data from file while plotting in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to add an offset to the data from a file which i want to plot using gnuplot. Suppose i want to add an offset of 0.001 to all the data values from file before i plot them . How can i do it in gnuplot without having to rewrite the data file with the offsets.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Try something like this:

```
plot "Data.dat" u ($1):($2 + 0.001) w l
```

The `$1` and `$2` specify the column you want to plot. Simply add a constant like `0.001` to the column or even add two columns like so: `$1 + $2`.

I hope that answers your quastion
Cherio Woltan

Comment: To clarify how to add offset to X column when not specifying X column:  Note that "$0 or column(0) returns the sequence number of this data record within a dataset." When you are plotting and just specifying the y-coord (e.g. 'plot "datafile" using 2 with lines') then you are implicitly using the column(0). That plot command is the same as 'plot "datafile" using 0:2 with lines'. To add an X-offset and/or Y-offset you can change it like this: 'plot "datafile" using ($0+17):($2+42) with lines'.

Comment: I have to say the whole shortcut syntax, especially in examples, makes it ever harder to read - was it really that much effort to write `with lines` instead of `w l` and `using` instead of `u`? gnuplot should really do away with the whole abbreviated syntax altogether. It does not serve *anybody* except perhaps spare the script interpreter some CPU time.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is better to let gnuplot compute offset, instead of guessing the right constant...

```
off(x) = sin(x) + offset
fit off(x) "data" using 1:2 via offset
plot off(x)
```